# How do I mock the .Where() extension of a mocked IQueryable<T> using NSubstitite

Tags: c#, tdd, azure-cosmosdb, xunit, nsubstitute

so the code under test is:

`var query = _documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<TEntity>(CollectionUri, GetFeedOptions()).AsQueryable();`

```
foreach (var filter in filters)
{
    query = query.Where(filter);      
}
```

It throws an exception at `query = query.Where(filter);` where my filter is a valid Expression.

The code works at runtime, and compiles, but my unit tests are throwing the exception:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: arg0

at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1)


at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)

at .DataAccess.Core.CosmoDbRepositoryBase`1.GetAsync(IEnumerable`1 filters, Int32 take, Boolean getAll) in C:\...DataAccess\Core\CosmoDbRepositoryBase.cs:line 223
```

However, my `arg0` is not null
[image: Debug View]
My Mock, using `XUnit` & `NSubstitute`, looks like this:

```
IDocumentClient _documentClient = Substitute.For<IDocumentClient>();
var document = new Document();
document.LoadFrom(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TestDataFactory.GetFakeResourceEntity()))));
var response = new ResourceResponse<Document>(document);
_documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(Arg.Any<Uri>(), Arg.Any<object>(), Arg.Any<RequestOptions>(), Arg.Any<bool>(), Arg.Any<CancellationToken>())
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(response));
```

Comment: static methods - ands that´s what extension-methods are - are hard to mock. Having said this you shouldn´t probily mock the where-statement, but replace the underlying collection by an in-memory one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mock `.Where(predicate)`. You mock `predicate` itself. Basically, `collection.Where(_ => true)` will always be just `collection` with no modification at all!